# Запись переменной в новую строку DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть переменная (в примере ниже - measurement), значение которой изменяется. Нужно записывать её каждое новое значение в новую строку датафрейма. Код

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Measurement': [str(measurement.payload.decode("utf-8"))]})
print(df)
```

создает датафрейм, но он сохраняет только одну свою строку. С каждой новой переменной единственная строка датафрейма обновляется, а нужно, чтобы каждая новая переменная записывалась в новую строку того же датафрейма.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для **первого** значения переменной создаем датафрейм так, как вы это уже сделали

*(применить функцию `str()` на строку не нужно; может быть вы хотели применить функцию `float()`):*

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Measurement': [measurement.payload.decode("utf-8")]})
```

Затем для **каждого следующего** (нового) значение используем то же самое, что и на правой стороне, т.е.

```
     pd.DataFrame({'Measurement': [measurement.payload.decode("utf-8")]})
```

но **добавим его к текущему датафрейму `df`** применением функции `pd.concat()`

```
df = pd.concat((df, 
                pd.DataFrame({'Measurement': [measurement.payload.decode("utf-8")]})),
                ignore_index=True)
```

---

*Пример с конкретными значениами вместо вашего `measurement.payload.decode("utf-8")`:*

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Measurement': [7.62]})
>>> df
```

> ```
>    Measurement
> 0         7.62
> ```

```
>>> df = pd.concat((df,
...                 pd.DataFrame({'Measurement': [3.14]})),
...                 ignore_index=True)
>>> df
```

> ```
>    Measurement
> 0         7.62
> 1         3.14
> ```

```
>>> df = pd.concat((df,
...                 pd.DataFrame({'Measurement': [2.72]})),
...                 ignore_index=True)
>>> df
```

> ```
>    Measurement
> 0         7.62
> 1         3.14
> 2         2.72
> ```

Comment: Но нужно учесть, что с ростом кол-ва строк такой подход будет работать всё медленнее и медленнее. )